# How do I properly setup transactional fixtures in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, fixtures

I just started a new project yesterday and I'm having a lot of very strange transactional fixture problems. It sounds like this is something of an issue with Rails, so I'm hoping StackOverflow can help. Here's the rundown.

- Coworkers can run tests fine. They are running Mac OS X; I'm running Ubuntu.
- When `use_transactional_fixtures` is `true`, lots of tests fail with `can't find [record] with ID=[some-id]`. My coworkers run in this mode, but experience no problems.
- If I set `use_transactional_fixtures` to `false`, almost all of the previously failing tests pass again. My coworkers don't see a difference, except that the tests run moderately slower since transactions aren't being used anymore.
- When tests are run *individually* (`rake spec SPEC=spec/some-specific-spec.rb`) with fixtures on `false`, there is a failure in test #1,234, and only test #1,234.
- When tests are run *all together* (`rake spec`) with fixtures on `false`, there is a failure in test #3,456, and only test #3,456.
- These two tests are not related in any apparent way. There are a lot of tests (over 5,000), so it doesn't seem terribly surprising that there might be a coincidence happening.

What inferences would you draw from this situation, and how would you go about fixing it?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is an issue with latest rails-rspec2:
http://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/issue/58